# Take several pictures and store in temporary path so user don't have access to them, then upload with the rest of the form

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I'm trying to develop a hybrid app with Intel xdk and cordova.

How would it be possible to take several pictures, store the path to them in a form, and then when "submit" button in the form is pressed, the pictures along with the other inserted information is sent to a database?

I don't want the user to be able to access the path or pictures.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as i know, any path that you create programmatically to store pictures can be accessed manually using file explorers in Android. May be you can delete the files available in device after submit.

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592531/how-to-make-user-click-5-pics-and-display-it-in-different-image-view-in-android/42598225#42598225

I show the steps you need to take to capture multiple pictures from the camera without returning to your app between each picture.